# How to disable hour in calendar view in odoo?

Tags: xml, calendar, odoo, odoo-8

Is there a generic way to disable hours in calendar views in Odoo?

I'm using the following code:

```xml
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="topay_pay_calendar_view">
    <field name="name">topay_pay.calendar</field>
    <field name="model">topay.pay</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <calendar string="To pay Calendar" date_start="date_start" date_end="date_exp" color="id">
            <field name="name"/>
            <field name="amount"/>
        </calendar>
    </field>
</record>
```

Comment: I have the same question, did you finally solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I just solved it. Here comes in place the **all_day** parameter. Try the following:

```
<calendar string="To pay Calendar" date_start="date_start" date_end="date_exp" color="id" all_day="date_start">
    <field name="name"/>
    <field name="amount"/>
</calendar>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Odoo 15 you can use `hide_time="true"`. It's not documented, but it works and there are still usages in the official code base.

Example:

```xml
<calendar hide_time="true">
    <field name="name"/>
    <field name="amount"/>
</calendar>
```

Override example for `stock.picking`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<odoo>
    <record model="ir.ui.view" id="stock_picking_calendar">
        <field name="name">my.stock_picking_calendar</field>
        <field name="model">stock.picking</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="stock.stock_picking_calendar"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <xpath expr="/calendar" position="attributes">
                <attribute name="hide_time">true</attribute>
            </xpath>
        </field>
    </record>
</odoo>
```

Answer (score -1):

For this you have to code in xml like this :

```html
<xpath expr="//kanban/templates//div[@class='oe_kanban_footer_left']" position="replace">
      <div class="oe_kanban_footer_left">
  
      </div>
</xpath>
```